# python class setter restrictions

Tags: python

I have a class and a property `writable_attributes` which is an array of attributes that should be available to bet set when the class is instantiated:

```
class User(object):
    writable_attributes = ['username','email']
```

I want to be able to raise an error if another attribute is set if it's not in the list of `writable_attributes`. I was browsing for a generic setter but I can't find anything to fit my needs. Something like:

```
user = User()
user.foo = 'bar' # This should raise an error since only `username` and `email` can be set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also be interested in `__setattr__`.  This overrides attribute setting on an object.  **slots** has additional complications that **setattr** doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're *really* looking for is [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: __slots__ gives me no chance of control while a setter might allow me to do some checking before throwing an error if the attribute is not writable. A generic setter would allow me for example to perform a check based on permissions to see if the current user is allowed to set that attribute or not.

Comment: That's what properties are for.

Answer (score 2):

First, reconsider if you really need to do this. It is usually over-engineering. If you do decide you *really* need to, take a look at [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) - if you rename your `writable_attributes` to `__slots__`, it will be an error to try to create more. If you need to avoid some existing ones being written to once they're set once, you can do that with properties.